# Concept to show additional field in a page via checkbox

Tags: html

Can someone give me an idea on how to show addition fields when someone clicks on checkbox.
Its like in a checkout where it asks if you have a coupon.
If you click it, then the page extends with another field right below the checkbox where we will get a textbox to enter the data.
What's the idea behind it?

Thanks

Comment: The idea behind it is a listener on the checkbox, if checked, create another field, if un-checked, remove said created field.

Comment: @tymeJV Easier yet, just hide/unhide that field.

Comment: You need `Javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to respond to the click or change event of the checkbox and then show some already existing HTML or add some dynamically.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx1" />
<div id="extraContent"><!-- hidden content --></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {

    $('#chkbx1').change(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('#extraContent').show();
        else
            $('#extraContent').hide();

    });

});
```

Comment: Important note, this is using the jQuery library :D

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I use it so much I just assume but that is a valid point to mention since the question does not mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use just straight Javascript,
you could have something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Coupon"id= "coupon"/> Coupon? <br>
<div style="display:none;" id="coupon_wrapper">
    <label>Coupon Code</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

With Javascript that reads

```
document.getElementById('coupon').addEventListener('change',function(){
    if(document.getElementById('coupon').checked){
        document.getElementById('coupon_wrapper').style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('coupon_wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    }
},false);
```